# How Java If statements work when having && AND ||

Tags: java, if-statement

If you write this in an if statement (this is an example):

```
if (A == 1 && B == 1
||
C == 1 && D == 1)
```

Does Java think like this: if A and B is equal to 1 OR C == 1 and D == 1, then it's true.
Or does Java think: if A and B or C is equal to 1 AND D is equal to 1, then it's true.
And there's more possibilities with AND and OR..

This is a problem in my programming because I'm not sure about this question.

/Viktor

Comment: operator== has an higher priority than operator&&, which has an highe r precedence than operator||

Comment: When it's unclear, add more brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so it is interpreted first. i.e., it's equivalent of

```
if ((A == 1 && B == 1)
    ||
    (C == 1 && D == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparison operator `==` has an higher priority than the `AND` logical operator `&&`, which has an higher precedence than the `OR` logical operator `||`. 
See documentation for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

In general, if you are not sure about the operators priority, use `brackets`.